# Correct way to cast a gpointer to a GType

Tags: types, macros, glib, gnome

I am trying to create a macro which will cast a `gpointer` to `GType` and vice versa. I have created the following macros to do this using the relevant [API documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Type-Conversion-Macros.html) as a guide:

```
#ifdef GTYPE_TO_POINTER
  #define GTYPE_TO_POINTER (x) (GSIZE_TO_POINTER (x))
#endif
#ifdef GPOINTER_TO_GTYPE
  #define GPOINTER_TO_GTYPE(p) (GPOINTER_TO_SIZE (p))
#endif
```

I have the casting done as follows:

```
type = (GType)g_hash_table_lookup(typeTable, GUINT_TO_POINTER(tflag));
```

I want to do the casting as follows:

```
type = GPOINTER_TO_GTYPE(g_hash_table_lookup(typeTable, GUINT_TO_POINTER(tflag)));

 // stuff

 g_hash_table_insert(typeTable,
                     GUINT_TO_POINTER(tflag),
                     GTYPE_TO_POINTER(type));
```

However, this seems to be problematic as my compiler is indicating an implicit declaration has been made with the `g_hash_table_lookup` cast and with the third argument of the following `g_hash_table_insert`

```
warning: implicit declaration of function 'GPOINTER_TO_GTYPE'          
warning: implicit declaration of function 'GTYPE_TO_POINTER'
warning: passing argument 3 of 'g_hash_table_insert' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
```

Also when I try to run the wrapper I get a `java: symbol lookup error` of an `undefined symbol: GPOINTER_TO_GTYPE`.

Can anyone advise on what I might be able to do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I seem to have figured it out myself now....

Firstly, I was using the wrong test in checking for `GTYPE_TO_POINTER` and `GPOINTER_TO_GTYPE` since they were the variables I wanted to define the compiler could not find them and the definition was never being made.

Secondly, I was using undefined variables as an argument so the correct definition for these macros seems to be:

```
#ifdef GPOINTER_TO_SIZE
  #define GPOINTER_TO_GTYPE(gpointer) (GPOINTER_TO_SIZE (gpointer))
#endif
#ifdef GSIZE_TO_POINTER
  #define GTYPE_TO_POINTER(gtype) (GSIZE_TO_POINTER(gtype))
#endif
```

Which means my casting functions now compile without problems.